# Cómo reproducir vídeos en VideoView

Tags: android

Tengo 15 botones en un `activity` y quiero que cuando se haga clic en un botón reproduzca un vídeo.

Lo que quiero es hacerlo sin usar varias `activity` por cada botón para enviar a reproducir el vídeo.

Comment: Hola Oscar, tu pregunta fue reportada como de baja calidad, recuerda que debes realizar preguntas en base a [ask], agrega más detalles, ejemplo del código que hayas realizado [mcve] saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes crear una Actividad que contenga el `VideoView`, esta Actividad debe recibir la **URL** del vídeo mediante `Intents`, ya con eso puedes rehusar la actividad para reproducir vídeos.

Ejemplo :

añades en tu XML

```
<VideoView
android:id="@+id/simpleVideoView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
```

Codigo Java :

**Paso 1**: cree un nuevo directorio en la carpeta res y asígnele el nombre raw

**Paso 2**: guarda un nombre de video fishvideo en la carpeta sin formato

**Paso 3**: Ahora usa el siguiente código para establecer la ruta del video usando el método setVideoUri () en VideoView.

```
// iniciar una vista de video
VideoView simpleVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById (R.id.simpleVideoView);
simpleVideoView.setVideoURI (Uri.parse ("android.resource: //" + getPackageName () + "/" + R.raw.fishvideo));
```

Te comparto un [link](http://blog.hunabsys.com/reproducir-video-con-videoview-en-android/) interesante.

Comment: Esta respuesta no soluciona la pregunta, el OP necesita 15 botones,¿ El nombre del archivo porque tiene que ser fishvideo? Te aconsejo realizar respuestas de preguntas que cumplan con lo definido en el [help].